# Is there an English word to define someone who qualifies their knowledge by (family) association?

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives, nouns

I know someone who consistently refers to the fact that their aunt/brother-in-law/cousin or someone in his family has the highest level of expertise to validate his comments to have the highest value.
For example: "I know that this kind of equipment is capable of this because my brother-in-law is a physicist."

Is there a noun to describe a person who qualifies his or her knowledge base by an association with an expert? Or perhaps a verb/adjective to describe the behavior?

The closest I could find is "Ultracrepidarian" however, the definition is not specific to "qualification by association".

Comment: Isn’t *ultracrepidarian* about advising on some matter that lies **outside** one’s area of expertise rather than within it?  Make of this what you will but it turns out that we have a surprisingly **large number** of [posts on our site that mention *ultracrepidarian*](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=ultracrepidarian).

Comment: It's a special case of the _association fallacy_ (and _honour by association fallacy_); I'm unaware of any name for the hyponym.

Comment: Yes, this person would be making comments about information outside their expertise but because “they know somebody” they believe that their facts are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Google shows that's [**name-dropping**](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS920US920&sxsrf=AJOqlzVSD7MNj6ALL3DSUBbZ9e_s3Nma9w:1673288995341&q=Name-dropping&si=AEcPFx5VsQIwuEhIk_AtXnxBGHwHLoTlVb-ROKBbAjrv45zB_8qNN3YSmSLDsKg5KGtmokHLjBpsog1nkO630Q6VKO42OafSfep6hoIPcI0jyXhQjKsUKk3gBxJHgsBRbpPLWWAGY6rWYTfkR3pcooVYS03nrkyJYrvliOnery29VkyY92CQJck%3D&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif3rGhj7v8AhU6kYkEHanmB1MQ6RN6BAgiEAE&biw=1304&bih=665&dpr=1)...

> ... the act of talking about famous people that you have met, often pretending that you know them better than you really do, in order to appear more important and special:
>
> *Her constant name-dropping is very irritating*.

Merriam-Webster shows the noun [name-dropping](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/name-dropper) as "the studied but seemingly casual mention of prominent persons as associates done to impress others."

Comment: Name-dropping is about people they will have *heard* of, to impress, for example "Feynman told me that" not a relative who happens to have some expertise.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority),

> An **argument from authority** (argumentum ab auctoritate), also called an appeal to authority, or argumentum ad verecundiam, is a form of argument in which the opinion of an authority on a topic is used as evidence to support an argument. Some consider that it is used in a cogent form if all sides of a discussion agree on the reliability of the authority in the given context, and others consider it to be a fallacy to cite the views of an authority on the discussed topic as a means of supporting an argument.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that crepidarius is the Latin for a rattlesnack, which makes a nasty noise but definitely also has a deadly sting.  So even as a metaphor it is not ideal.

More than that, from the account, it is impossible to tell whether this person is a jerk because he really does know the people their claims actually are correct, or whether they are a phony jerk, or so I thought till I looked into the Cambridge English Dictionary.

To my surprise, however, the Cambridge English Dictionary does have a definition for it.

> someone who has no special knowledge of a subject but who expresses an opinion about it:

- I avoid commenting on football for fear of being called an ultracrepidarian.

The problem with this perfect fit is that scarcely anyone would understand it. I cannot think of any way of trapping them into "knowing a lexicographer who ..."  If I could, you would easily find out which kind of jerk they were.

In any case, the example leaves a doubt:  many a football fan could be not inappropriately be described as a *crepidarian*, rattle in hand. And unkind people do say that the football crepidarian often claims more football expertise than he has, making him the *fons et origo* of ultracrepidarianism.

---